# Minimum quantity and increase with minimum quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, price, products, quantity

I would like to have a product with a **minimum quantity** of **25** and if someone wants to order more and press on the arrow for more it needs to jump to **50**, **75** etc.

My product is only available per **25**. Is it also possible to update the price per click?

**If anythings is unclear, feel free to ask for info!**

Comment: Enable Qty Increments is 25

Comment: @RkRathod Where can i find that?

Comment: check answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In This Case Product Qty Increments 25 define.**

**In Admin Side Open That Product**

```
Catalog > Manage Product > Inventory > Enable Qty Increments
```

**Replace 25 to 1**